# Promisify chrome API using Bluebird

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, async-await, bluebird

I'm trying to promisify chrome.storage.sync.get using Bluebird.js. I see that all the examples on the bluebird http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/working-with-callbacks.html site use `Promise.promisify(require(someAPI))`. I tried doing 
`const storageGet = Promise.promisify(chrome.storage.sync.get);` ( I don't have a require if that affects anything), and then calling

```
async function() {
  return await storageGet('config', function (result) {
    // do stuff
  })
};
```

Console error was

```
Unhandled rejection Error: Invocation of form get(string, function, function) 
doesn't match definition get(optional string or array or object keys, function 
callback)
```

My understanding (granted little understanding of Promises and bluebird) is that storageGet is being passed the wrong parameters? But chrome.storage.sync.get needs to be passed a string and a callback function so I'm not particularly sure what's going wrong. Also I could be completely off in how I'm promisifying chrome storage.

I am aware that there is an example with chrome promisifying at http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html#option-promisifier, but I'm honestly not too familiar with promises to understand what's going on in that example.

Is there a certain way I should be promisifying chrome storage than the way I'm doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Callback API of function that you want to promisify with Bluebird has to conform to the NodeJS callback convention: "error-first, single-parameter" (as stated [HERE](https://gist.github.com/CrabDude/10907185)). According to the [storage sync documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#type-StorageArea) its API does not conform to the one required by Bluebird:

```
StorageArea.get(string or array of string or object keys, function callback)

/* Callback with storage items, or on failure (in which case runtime.lastError will be set).

The callback parameter should be a function that looks like this:

function(object items) {...};*/
```

There's no error parameter at all. This method is not even throwing any error. It exposes only the result. You can easily turn it into Promise-based API by wrapping given method with `Promise`:

```
function getFromStorageSync(key) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function(items) {
      resolve(items)
    })
  })
}

getFromStorageSync('someKey').then(function(items) { console.log(items) })
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit more generic and will catch errors when `chrome.runtime.lastError` is set.

```
/**
 * Converts asynchronous chrome api based callbacks to promises
 *
 * @param {function} fn
 * @param {arguments} arguments to function
 * @returns {Promise} Pending promise returned by function
 */
var promisify = function (fn) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).slice(1);
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    fn.apply(null, args.concat(function (res) {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        return reject(chrome.runtime.lastError);
      }
      return resolve(res);
    }));
  });
};
```